# Introduction to the Ben Ish Chai

Tags: jewish-books, ben-ish-chai

Which one of the Ben Ish Chai's books is the best introduction to his thought and work?

Comment: Probably Ben Ish Chai?

Comment: He has a great into to Rav Pe'alim about derech hapesak, but it's not an introduction to his own derech in kol hatorah.

Comment: Oh, you mean which sefer is itself a broad enough demonstration of how he works in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aderet Eliyahu](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Aderet_Eliyahu_(Rabbi_Yosef_Chaim)), a collection of Rav Yosef Chaim's commentaries on the weekly Parsha and Haftara, is an excellent gateway into his writings.

It has also been published in a well-written [English translation](https://seforimcenter.com/Aderet-Eliyahu---Derashot-on-the-Parasha--Haftarah-Rabbi-Yosef-Chaim-/-English---2-vol.__p-9514.aspx), no small feat for a book containing so many kaballistic concepts.